# Integral of a 2-form on a smoothly parametrized surface

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

I am studying Stokes' Theorem and its applications, and dealing with the following two problems:

> 1. Consider the surface $ S ={(x, y, z) \mid z=1-x^{2}-y^{2}>0}$. Find a smooth parametrisation $H$ of $S$ and then calculate the integral of the 2 -form $\omega=x \mathrm{~d} y \wedge \mathrm{d} z+$ $y \mathrm{~d} z \wedge \mathrm{d} x+z \mathrm{~d} x \wedge \mathrm{d} y$ over this surface.
>
> 2. Use Stokes' Theorem to calculate the integral of the 2 -form
>
> $$
> \omega=y \mathrm{~d} y \wedge \mathrm{d} z+z \mathrm{~d} z \wedge \mathrm{d} x+\mathrm{d} x \wedge \mathrm{d} y
> $$
> over the hemisphere $(x, y, z) \mid x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=1, z>0$ oriented so that the normal vector points up.

For 1), I considered to use the polar coordinates: $H(r,\theta) = (rcos\theta, rsin\theta, 1-r^2)$, where H is defined on $U = \{ (r,\theta) : 0<\text{r}<1, 0<\theta<2\pi \}$. Then using definition of integrals of 2-forms, I can get

$\int_{H(U)} \omega = \int_U H^*(\omega)$

Then I computed $H^*(\omega)$ and calculated the resulting double integral as equal to $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ (I am adding my calculations below). The problem is I am not even sure that my change of variables function $H$ is correct.

For 2), I do not know really how to proceed. I am especially confused about the part "so that the normal vector points up." What should I understand from this?
Note: both problems are from Joseph Taylor, "Foundations of Analysis". My level is not above of that book.

[image: My solution for 1)]

Comment: They needed to tell you the orientation in part (a) as well. The value of the integral changes sign if you change orientation. Is $dr\wedge d\theta$ compatible with that orientation or opposite? …. For (b) note that $d\omega=0$, so if you close up the surface (add another piece), the total integral will be $0$. You can find literally dozens of such examples on this site.

Comment: Sorry, in part (a) it was added that "with normal vector pointing up". But still I do not know the meaning of this, nor its connection with $\mathrm{~d} r \wedge \mathrm{d} \theta$. For part (b), if $d\omega=0$, can't we directly conclude that the integral is zero, over any surface?

Comment: Your course must have talked about orientation. I can’t mind-read how, but it must have. I can suggest you look at some of my YouTube videos (linked in my profile) on forms and surface integrals. … Re (b), over any *closed* surface, yes. Is the integral of. $dx\wedge dy$ over every surface $0$?

Comment: so are you suggesting finding the integral over $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and then taking the negative of the result? If so, I considered the following: $\omega= d\phi$, then I get a 1-form $\phi$. Then if I can parametrize  $x^2 + y^2 = 1$  correctly by an equivalent path $\gamma$, I can use Stokes' theorem and calculate $\int_{\gamma} \phi$? Maybe I can take $\gamma(t)= (cost,sint)$? The reason I change from $\omega$ to $\phi$  is that the second one seems much more familiar. (The thing is that I missed so many courses and currently trying to catch up, they did mention orientation as you said...)

Comment: No, I meant to include the disk $z=0, x^2+y^2\le 1$. Way easier than using Stokes’s Theorem the way you did. Sometimes it’s very hard (and occasionally impossible!) to find such a $\phi$. Again, I recommend my videos for many examples of surface integrals and Stokes’s Theorem.